# how i can populate a html table from a local text file?

Tags: php, html

i have this php code to read a text file, and generate a html table, but i don't want to include the file name in the code, this file name should come from a text file which is yet to be uploaded, can you give the solution to this ?

```
<?php
    $filepath = 'files/the_file.txt';

    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        $file = fopen($filepath, 'r');
        echo '<table border=1>';
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            $first_char = $line[0];
            if ($first_char != '*' && $first_char != '^' && trim($line) != '') {
                if (strstr($line, '|')) {
                    $split = explode('|', $line);
                    echo '<tr>';
                    foreach($split as $line) {
                        echo '<td>'.$line.'</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                } else {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$line.'</td></tr>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'the file does not exist';
    }
?>
```

i don't want to specify the file path before-hand, it should be read after the file is uploaded in the html page as below,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

but again there is the code for uploading the file also, upload_file.php,

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just post your form to the php file with form generation and replace statin $filepath to 
`$filepath = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];`

upload_file.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES[file]) 
    && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK
    && file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {

    $filepath = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $file = fopen($filepath, 'r');
    echo '<table border=1>';
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $first_char = $line[0];
        if ($first_char != '*' && $first_char != '^' && trim($line) != '') {
            if (strstr($line, '|')) {
                $split = explode('|', $line);
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach($split as $line) {
                    echo '<td>'.$line.'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            } else {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$line.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo 'the file does not exist';
}
```

Comment: ok, now i want to display the uploaded file in the same page, how to do this ?

Comment: i have tried the above code, but still with that code also, it is displaying the contents in another new page, i want to display the contents of the uploaded file in the same page without disturbing the other components, can you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You have all the code you need right there. :)
You just need to wrap your main table generation code in an if statement that will check to see if the file uploaded okay:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    if (file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $file = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');

        // Rest of CODE to generate your table
}
```

Note that your uploaded file will eventually get deleted if you don't move it using move_uploaded_file().

Comment: ok, now i want to display the uploaded file in the same page, how to do this ?

Comment: How so? Do you just want a link to it? Is the file going to be persistant to a specific user, or all users? I'm unclear how you want this to get displayed.